Print layout label using attribute table entry using QGIS
I am trying to populate a text label in a print layout with a value from a field in the attribute table for a single selected feature.
In my project I have one layer. I filter this layer down to a single feature, using a field from the attribute table called Refval. I want to display the entry for Refval from the attribute table in a text label in print layout view.
I imagine I need to select the label from the Items menu in print layout view, then in the Main Properties box I should  insert syntax for an expression, using the Insert Expression box opens. I don’t know the correct syntax for the expression though.

There may be a way to pass the value to a variable that the layout can use in the 'insert expression' box.  Trying it now.
